# Using ng-repeat to repeat different directives?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I define different directives like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',["ngTouch"]);

app.directive('controlLed',function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       replace: true,
       scope: true,
       templateUrl: 'controlLed.html'
   }
});

app.directive('controlPlug',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'controlPlug.html'
    }
});

app.directive('controlTemp',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'controlTemp.html'
    }
});

app.directive('controlDoor',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        templateUrl: 'controlDoor.html'
    }
});
```

each directive has a different view model. Now I use ajax to return a json structure like this:

```
  "device_list":{
    "d0": {
       name:led1,
       model:controlLed
    },
    "d1": {
       name:led2,
       model:controlLed
    },
    "d2": {
      name:plug1,
      model:controlPlug
    },
    "d3": {
      name:Temp1,
      model:controlTemp
    },
    "d4": {
      name:Door,
      model:controlDoor
    }
}
```

I want to use the ng-repeat to generate the following view of the results:

```
<div class="content">
    <control-led></control-led>
    <control-led></control-led>
    <control-plug></control-plug>
    <control-temp></control-temp>
    <control-door></control-door>
</div>
```

What should I do?

Comment: Can we update json structute?

Comment: What is device_list do, d1, d2..... Do you need this data in your directive. Do you need to pass individual device data to respective directive based on their order or simply want iterate against all directive for each device data?

Comment: yes I want to use ajax data to update my view model.Each time may return different value!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over you JSON data to create the HTML you require and utilize the $compile service to compile the generated HTML like below

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('mCTRL',function($scope){
  $scope.myJSONData=[{
       name:'led2',
       model:'controlplug'
    },{
       name:'led1',
       model:'controlled'
    }]

})
```

Your directives

```
app.directive('controlled',function() {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       scope: true,
        replace:true,
       template: '<div>controlLed.html</div>'
   }
});

app.directive('controlplug',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        replace:true,
        template: '<div>controlPlug.html</div>'
    }
});
```

Create a new directive which will create dynamic template based upon your JSON data

```
app.directive('main',function($compile){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
       replace: true,
       link(scope,elem,attrs)
       {
         debugger;
         var html='';

         for(var i=0;i<scope.myJSONData.length;i++)
         {
           debugger;
           var model=scope.myJSONData[i].model;
           html+=$compile("<div><"+model+"><"+model+"/><div/>")(scope).html()
         }
         elem.replaceWith(html);

       }

  }

})
```

***Note:*** This way you can make your code generic and in future if you have to add some more directives you only have to add it in your JSON and it will pick the correct directive and render it, you don't have to change your view every time for it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-switch` inside an `ng-repeat` to load the appropriate directive. Assuming you have `$scope.device_list` in your controller, you would use something like:

```
<div class="content" ng-repeat="device in device_list">
    <div ng-switch="device.model">
        <div ng-switch-when="controlLed">
            <control-led></control-led>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="controlPlug">
            <control-plug></control-plug>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="controlTemp">
            <control-temp></control-temp>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="controlDoor">
            <control-door></control-door>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

This is the code used to solve my problem (based on the answer by Lex).

```
<div class="content" ng-controller="device-panel">
    <div  ng-repeat="device in devicelist" ng-switch on="device.model">
        <div ng-switch-when="controlLed">
            <control-led></control-led>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="controlPlug">
            <control-plug></control-plug>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="controlTemp">
            <control-temp></control-temp>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="controlDoor">
            <control-door></control-door>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```